# Horizontal menu center elements

Tags: html, css, menu, center, horizontallist

I have the following files:

**html file**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><b><a href="">Alle Rezepte</a></b></li>
        <li><b><a href="">Alle Zutaten</a></b></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

**css file**

```
nav {
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;   
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

**And it looks like this in the browser**
[image]

But I want the two elements two be center in their own half, like this

```
|----------li1-----------|---------li2------------|
```

instead of

```
|---------------------li1|li2---------------------|
```

What do I have to add to my code have it the way I want it?

Comment: nav ul li {float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; list-style: none;}

Comment: Please try my updated version, because all others will work only with 2 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this: **Updated** **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d11dv0nu/4/)**

```
 nav {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #666;
}
nav ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 15px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #666;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This version works perfectly, with many items as well as with very long items, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` and `text-align`:

```
li {float: left; width: 50%; text-align: center; list-style: none;}
li a {display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gLkdaw5/

Comment: What if we add third element in list?

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan I would be interested too, because later I want to add more elements without rewriting the css.

Comment: @danielr1996: just change 50% to (`100% / number of items`).

Comment: You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/5gLkdaw5/1/

You can try my variant, it will be work with all counts of items

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan: you downvoted because of _what if ..._? 1. in question were two items, not _what if_. 2. using `display: table(-cell)` I need to declare `cell`s width if I want to have all items of the same width. Without declaring width the cell with longer text will be longer.

Comment: Just add table-layout:fixed;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/691/

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngpjkmac/)

You can use `display:table;`

```
nav ul {
  text-align: center;   
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

nav ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the li a width.

see it all here http://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/bdVZJP

CSS:

```
nav ul {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
}

.example {
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 46%;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="example"><b><a href="">Alle Rezepte</a></b></li>
    <li class="example"><b><a href="">Alle Zutaten</a></b></li>
</ul>   
</nav>
```